# typoscript data and where

Tags: typo3, typoscript

`col2.10.data = DB:pages:{$plugin.mx_esyswebsite.settings.navigation.footerSecondColEntry}:title` reads the title from the record with the uid `$plugin.mx_esyswebsite.settings.navigation.footerSecondColEntry` from the pages table.

Now I need for english the value from the table pages_language_overlay. But here there must be a where clause instead of the uid:

```
where pid = $plugin.mx_esyswebsite.settings.navigation.footerSecondColEntry
```

How can I do this?

```
col1.10.data = DB:pages_language_overlay:???{$plugin.tx_esyswebsite.settings.navigation.footerFirstColEntry}:title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the RECORDS object TYPO3 will handle the language overlay automatically. Documentation is here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html